# Issue with cursor in MYSQL proceure

Tags: mysql

The following procedure works almost perfeclty with one exception. The first select returns two records. However, in the loop it builds three cases as though it goes around three times. Can't figure it out. Something obvious I'm not seeing.

```
DECLARE DTE DATE;
DECLARE EXIT_LOOP BOOLEAN;
DECLARE DATECURSOR CURSOR FOR

SELECT DISTINCT DATE
FROM SCHEDULE
WHERE BKFST > 0;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET EXIT_LOOP = TRUE;

OPEN DATECURSOR;

SET @s = '';

DATE_LOOP: LOOP

        FETCH DATECURSOR INTO DTE;

        SET @s = CONCAT(@s,CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN SCHEDULE.DATE =', "'", DTE, "'", ' THEN SCHEDULE.', _TYPE,' END) AS ', "'", DTE ,"', "));

        IF EXIT_LOOP THEN
         CLOSE DATECURSOR;
         LEAVE DATE_LOOP;
        END IF;


END LOOP DATE_LOOP;

SET @s = TRIM(trailing ', ' from @s);

SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT MOW_ID, FUNDING, ',@s,' FROM SCHEDULE GROUP BY MOW_ID, FUNDING');

SELECT @q;

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt1;
commit;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```